# Problem Set Solutions to 'Semantics in Generative Grammar' (Heim & Kratzer)?

Tags: syntax, semantics, generative-grammar

I'm working through Heim and Kratzer's 1998 textbook 'semantics in generative grammar' (Blackwell), which I understand is fairly standard for university level courses on semantics, but I can't find any solutions to the problem sets.  Does anyone know where I can find these? Alternatively, if there's some sort of online database where I could find solutions to problems like the ones I'm here encountering?

EDIT: Here are a couple of the problems I could use some help with.

[image: problems]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the text.  The name "problem set" suggests that perhaps you are supposed to work out the solutions yourself.  Perhaps you could give us a sample problem so we could help?

Comment: Good idea, posted a couple problems.

Comment: Thank you.  I would not be able to do these exercises without doing some research, so I doubt I can help. I don't know how to "Schonfinkel" a function, for instance.  In very general terms, I think you need to know about predicate logic and the elements of set theory, and probably Montague grammar, to do them, depending on how much help your textbook gives.